# Добавить строки в датафрейм

Tags: python, dataframe

Как добавить пустые строки в начале датафрейма, 10 штук?  `df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['NaN'], '2': ['NaN']})` А как их заполнить значениями сразу из самой первой строки оригинала? Например  `df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['100'], '2': ['120']})` - строим 10 строк до строки 100, 120 и заполняем первой строкой оригинального датафрейма 100, 200.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите у pandas функции DataFrame.append() и pandas.concat(). Второй вопрос не понял, но надеюсь пример прояснит

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'1': [100], '2': [200]})

# Пустые строки в начале добавить
blank_count = 10
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({c: ['NaN'] for c in df1})] * blank_count, ignore_index=True)
df3 = df2.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

# Первую строку размножить и добавить в конец строку
fill_count = 10
df4 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'1': [100], '2': [120]})] * fill_count, ignore_index=True)
df5 = pd.concat([df4, df1], ignore_index=True)
```